# Project Euler #2 Efficiency

Tags: java, programming-challenge, fibonacci-sequence

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms.
>
> By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> ```
> 1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,...
> ```
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed N, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

I'd like to reduce the complexity of my code.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
            BigInteger input = sc.nextBigInteger();
            System.out.println(calculate(input));
        }
    }

    public static BigInteger calculate(BigInteger input) {
        BigInteger fib1 = new BigInteger("0");
        BigInteger fib2 = new BigInteger("1");
         BigInteger sum = new BigInteger("0");

        BigInteger fib = new BigInteger("0");
        while (input.compareTo(fib)>0) {

            if (fib.doubleValue() % 2 == 0)
                sum = sum.add(fib);
            fib = fib1.add(fib2);
            fib1 = fib2;
            fib2 = fib;

        }

        return sum;
    }

}
```

Comment: The Project Euler solution guide regarding this problem gives an improvement that reduces runtime by a factor of (at least) 3.  True, it's not an order of magnitude, but watching those constants will help you in other problems.

Comment: There have been answers (now deleted) questioning the sharing of project euler solutions. There is a [meta post about project euler solutions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/157/project-euler-solutions) here (and more generally [here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/keeping-competitive-results-private)) (to summarize: it is know that they would prefer solutions not to be shared, but CodeReview will still accept them. Stating that it is a project euler solution in the title is encouraged, so that people who don't want spoilers can avoid them).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The test

```
if (fib.doubleValue() % 2 == 0)
```

does not produce the correct result for numbers with more than 17 digits, because
that exceeds the precision of a double. Actually it returns `true` for `8944394323791464` and all subsequent Fibonacci numbers.
That is not relevant for the concrete problem here (see below), but *if* you want to work with `BigInteger` then you should replace this with

```
if (fib.remainder(bigTwo).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
```

where `bigTwo` is defined as

```
BigInteger bigTwo = new BigInteger("2");
```

[Project Euler Problem #2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2)
asks for the sum of all even-valued Fibonacci values not exceeding 4 million,
so using `BigInteger` is not really necessary. All numbers fit into the range
of `int`, and the above test simplifies to

```
if (fib % 2 == 0)
```

(I also planned to tell that using `int` instead of `BigInteger` makes the
program more *efficient*, but it turned out that the difference in running
time is not significant.)

Answer (score 3):

First off, I'm not sure whether you are targeting Java 7 or Java 8.

If you are targeting Java 7, this looks like a nice solution. The only things I can see are a small nit (the if statement should have curly braces around the consequent) and that the names for `fib`, `fib1`, and `fib2` could be more descriptive. Possibly `fibNext`, `fibCurrent`, and `fibPrevious` respectively?

If you are targeting Java 8, you can use [Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to decouple each individual step. You'd need to make a `FibbonachiIterator` class that implements `Iterator<BigInteger>` which just generates Fibonacci numbers, turn it into a stream, filter out the odd Fibonacci numbers, and then reduce with `BigInteger.add`. It'll be longer, and implementing `Iterator` could be seen as more complex, but the usage of the iterator is simpler.